# how to display matches characters in preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I'd like to string matching with regular expression by using preg_match() This is my code

```
<?php
$string = preg_match("/http\:\/\//","http");
echo $stirng;
?>
```

That is working well. But i want to display that what is the matching characters. how to do that?

Comment: manual page seems clear: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: The third parameter captures, but you aren't capturing anything. `:` is not a special character and doesnt need to be escaped. If you change the delimiter `/` also wont need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $matches another parameter inside the preg_match function. Like this

```
<?php
preg_match("/http\:\/\//","http://",$matches);
// this $matches echo out as a array object then,
print_r($matches);
?>
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: But you should write in your matching string as http://. If not do that you. That is not echo out anything